# ORM tool with support for Multiple databases

Tags: c#-4.0, orm, multiple-databases

I am looking for an ORM tool, which can support SQLServer/Oracle/MySql, etc.
I have used entity framework earlier and not very sure if that can achieve this flexibility. But I also loved the ease and great integration in visual studio. I have also considered NHibernate, but I have no experience with it.
So I am kind of undecisive, google returned a lot of ORM tools, like SubSonic, FluentNHibernate, etc.

Since, I am very close on picking up NHibernate and unsure of the issues it has, can someone who has worked on NHibernate as well as Entity Framework give a quick comparison on ease of use, the learning curve needed, support for LINQ, etc for NHibernate?

Note: The most important factors for me is the ability to switch to different database types (SQLServer/Oracle, etc) and performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Feature-by-Feature comparision](http://temebele.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/entity-framework-vs-nhibernate-feature-by-feature-comparison/) of Entity Framework and NHibernate.